# Problem of plotting graph when I use simplify, in graph

Tags: r, plot, graph, igraph, statnet

I want to plot my graph. I provided a sample data set.
I used simplify to remove loop, but it completely affect the structure of data. When I plot the data without using simplify, I have the correct colouring of vertex and edges but there is loop.

I used simplify to remove the loop and the colouring after it, is wrong, because each node and edge from it should have the same colour as I defined in the code.

does anyone know how to remove loop in plot to not affect the structure of data?

plot 1 : correct colouring but with loop

[image]

plot 2: wrong colouring after using simplify

[image]

The code:

```
      X user.screen_name           child       parent in_reply_to_screen_name vaccine_type label
1     0   TweeetLorraine 1.392218e+18 1.392218e+18                       1  AstraZeneca     0
2     1       phldenault 1.393259e+18 1.392218e+18          TweeetLorraine  AstraZeneca     2
41   40  ElizabethDuncan 1.392297e+18 1.392218e+18          TweeetLorraine  AstraZeneca     2
42   41          7Rose75 1.392294e+18 1.392218e+18          TweeetLorraine  AstraZeneca     1
43   42      wh0careswh0 1.392336e+18 1.392294e+18                 7Rose75  AstraZeneca     0
44   43   T_ProudVeteran 1.392330e+18 1.392294e+18                 7Rose75  AstraZeneca     2
45   44   TweeetLorraine 1.392294e+18 1.392294e+18                 7Rose75  AstraZeneca     2
46   45         Norlaine 1.392288e+18 1.392218e+18          TweeetLorraine  AstraZeneca     2
47   46    elham95264575 1.393212e+18 1.392288e+18                Norlaine  AstraZeneca     1
48   47      soyfreemike 1.392387e+18 1.392288e+18                Norlaine  AstraZeneca     0
49   48          KMTCarr 1.392288e+18 1.392218e+18          TweeetLorraine  AstraZeneca     2
50   49     angela_petta 1.392283e+18 1.392218e+18          TweeetLorraine  AstraZeneca     2
51   50     lhoneyimhome 1.392272e+18 1.392218e+18          TweeetLorraine  AstraZeneca     2
```

```
net1 <- graph_from_data_frame(df %>% select("child","parent")) 
rel = get.adjacency(graph, sparse = FALSE) 

graph = simplify(net1, remove.loops=TRUE)
graph
summary(graph)


vertex_attr(graph, "label") <- df$label
#Set edge attribute:
edge_attr(graph, "label") <- df$label




E(graph)$color[E(graph)$label == 2] <- '#B3DE69' #green
E(graph)$color[E(graph)$label == 1] <- '#80B1D3' #yellow
E(graph)$color[E(graph)$label == 0] <- '#FB8072'#purple

V(graph)$color[V(graph)$label == 2] <- '#B3DE69'
V(graph)$color[V(graph)$label == 1] <- '#80B1D3'
V(graph)$color[V(graph)$label == 0] <- '#FB8072'
g<-c('#B3DE69','#80B1D3','#FB8072')
plot(graph,layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold,
     vertex.frame.color=NA,vertex.label.color="black",
     edge.label = NA,
     vertex.size=3, usecurve=TRUE,
     edge.lwd=0.02,
     vertex.dist=10,vertex.label.dist=2,vertex.label.cex=0.9,
     pad=0.9,alpha=80,
     edge.arrow.size=.1)


legend("bottomleft",legend= c("Positive","Neutral","Negative"),
       col=g,pch=19,pt.cex=1.5,bty="n",
       title="Label category")

title(main="Visualization ", cex.main=1)
```

Comment: Igraph vertex and edge IDs (in other words, the order of vertices and edges) is not guaranteed to be preserved across operations adding or removing vertices or edges. This includes `simplify`. And I don't understand why you create a graph, then an adj matrix, and then again a graph. Assigning labels after that, directly from the original data frame doesn't guarantee a correct identity of the vertices.

Comment: yes those two line I deleted. it was a mistake. but do you think there is a way to deal with loop ? but not affecting the structure of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically it's easier to manipulate data in the data frame than in igraph attributes. I would suggest to prepare everything in the data frame before converting it to a graph. Then `simplify` will do it's job as it's supposed to do, and you can plot or analyse your graph as you wish. To preserve the edge attributes in `simplify` if `remove.multiple` is `TRUE`, you need to define the `edge.attr.comb` parameter. Below I used `dplyr::first`, meaning that we pick the first value at combining multiple edges.

**Edit: using OP data & preserving edge attributes in `simplify`**

```
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(tibble)
library(rlang)
library(readr)

df <- read_tsv('so_user142_data.tsv', col_types = cols())

color_map <- c(
    '0' = '#B3DE69', # green
    '1' = '#80B1D3', # blue
    '2' = '#FB8072'  # salmon
)

df %<>%
    mutate(label = recode(label, !!!color_map)) %>%
    rename(color = label) %>%
    select(
        child = user.screen_name,
        parent = in_reply_to_screen_name,
        color
    )


vertex_colors <-
    bind_rows(
        df %>% select(name = child, color),
        df %>% select(name = parent, color)
    ) %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    summarize_all(first) %>%
    ungroup

g <-
    df %>%
    graph_from_data_frame(vertices = vertex_colors) %>%
    simplify(edge.attr.comb = first)

png('so_user142_graph.png', 800, 800)

    plot(
        g,
        layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold,
        vertex.frame.color = NA,
        vertex.label.color = 'black',
        vertex.size = 7,
        edge.curved = TRUE,
        edge.lwd = 0.4,
        vertex.dist = 10,
        vertex.label.dist = 1.2,
        vertex.label.cex = 1.2,
        pad = 0.9,
        alpha = 80,
        edge.arrow.size = 1.
    )

dev.off()
```

[image: The graph as plotted above]

Comment: thank a lot , but your solution works for the data that you used for and it produced error to mine. asError in graph_from_data_frame(., vertices = vertex_colors) : 
  Some vertex names in edge list are not listed in vertex data frame

Comment: Can you maybe try with my data? thank you

Comment: I just read the DataFrame in the beginning of the your code instead of tibble

Comment: Also it doest color the edge based on label.

Comment: I modified the example accordingly. The only important update here is that you need to define `edge.attr.comb` in `simplify`.